# How to split or populate these values into LinkedList because they reside in 1 index

Tags: java, linked-list

[[a, b], [a, c], [b, c]] these values (subsets) are residing in 1 index of LinkedList.

How to split or populate these values like [a,b] on 1 index and [a,c] on 2nd? Because I want to compare these values to another LinkedList in Java.

Comment: Need a little more information on the criteria; such as where does `[b, c]` go?  Give an example of current data, and a separate block of desired results.  Indent the examples with 4 spaces for readability.

Comment: criteria is simple , i just want to separate them like [a,b] goes on 1 index, [a,c] on 2nd and [b,c] on 3rd respectively. now they all are residing in 1 index. hope u got the idea.